# auto-complete twitter handles and hashtags in twittering mode

Tags: auto-complete-mode, twitter

Is it possible to use auto-complete with twittering-mode to complete twitter handle names and hashtags?

Comment: Yes.  Is that your entire question?

Comment: @wasamasa, question was does twittering mode already supports this?

Answer (score -1):

Escape-x to access command mode, enter the emacs command to complete twitter handle names and hashtags, type the hashtag, hit the space bar to auto-complete.  Use the space bar to find the appropriate emacs command in command mode.

Comment: will you please let me know exact interactive function name to complete hashtag/handle?